# Text take up remaining width next to set width image

Tags: css, html

I am trying to make a paragraph take the remaining width of the window next to an image that has a width of 200px.

```
<section>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <img src='#' width='200'>
<section>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bu00y453/

Comment: Please show us what research you have done and attempts you have made at solving this problem

Answer (score 2):

You only need to set the `float:left` on the images, so that the paragraphs text can flow next to it. Plus: with a right margin, it looks a little nicer.

Try to put the image before the paragraph that should flow next to it in the source code.

```css
/* 
Part 2 - CSS
Style the content here. Make the content look good!
*/

#content {
  margin: 0px 20px;
}
header {
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!--
Part 2 - HTML
Instructions:
Write semantic markup for the following content. Lay out the page such that
the pictures are to one side of the blocks of content. 
-->
<section id='content'>
  <header>
    <h1>Why Do They? Heat-Seeking Kitties</h1>
    <h3>Your cat has good reasons for craving his fun in the sun.</h3>
  </header>
  <section class='article'>
    <img id='first-image' src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5081/5261689090_255c9173b6_n.jpg" width="200" alt="sunbathing">
    <p id='first-par'>Like tiny kittens seek out their mamas, cats find warm spots every chance they get. This is the first sensory indulgence cats develop, and they don't ever seem to lose it, says John C. Wright, Ph.D., a Certified Applied Animal Behaviorist and Professor
      of Psychology at Mercer University in Macon, Georgia.</p>
  </section>
  <section class='article'>
    <p id='second-par'>"For the newborn, t source of something warm and soft is Mom's belly, which also is where the kitten finds nourishment and a cuddly place to snooze," Dr. Wright says. Warmth has beneficial physical effects, too, as it helps soothe older cats' aches.
      Cats with arthritis love to curl up on soft blankets or snuggle with their owners. Some experts also say cats love hot spots because they were originally desert animals. It's an instinct of their ancestors. Some Like it Hot Some cats will do anything
      for the heat they crave. Muffin, a female Tortoiseshell, liked to lie on a gas space-heater. "We couldn't let her lie there because it was dangerous," says owner Audrey Pavia of Santa Ana, California. Pavia's other cat, Simba, used to lie on a window
      perch even in the summer. "She was so 'drunk' from the heat that she staggered a few steps and then sat down before she started moving again," Pavia says.</p>

    <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6168/6228843045_da7dcdcc0d_n.jpg" width="240" height="320" alt="Sunbathing">
  </section>
  <p>If you're looking for ways to warm your kitty, you might consider buying or building a window perch. Cats love a cozy chair or bed, too, provided there is ample sunlight. Heating pads are not recommended.</p>

  Other Cat Articles A Cat's Natural Instincts http://www.iams.com/pet-health/cat-article/a-cats-natural-instincts Adult Cat Feeding 101 http://www.iams.com/pet-health/cat-article/feeding-your-adult-cat-101-the-right-food-for-ages-one-to-six Crazy About
  Catnip http://www.iams.com/pet-health/cat-article/crazy-about-catnip
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the text to appear next to the image but not wrap around it, you can use `overflow: hidden` on the paragraph.

Here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wu94qpLt/

Answer (score 0):

you can calculate this in width

```
width:calc(100% - 200px);
```

add that to your paragraph

Comment: Is there a way to do this using margin/padding only?

Comment: No because the element doesnt know how much space is available and if it is getting to large it breaks. You can give it padding but than you have to set     box-sizing: border-box; on your paragraph so the padding gets calculated within the width.